# How to obtain Social Account Links shown in about page from Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't find the field/edge from the User object of Facebook's graph API.

[image: Facebook User Social Networks]

From a Facebook Page you can obtain it through the field `screennames` but it appears a bit different in the UI and doesn't always get linked with the Social account URL.

[image: Facebook Page Social Networks]

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn’t look like this is available via API.